# Prove or disprove that if $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are bounded sequences then $\{c_n\}$ is bounded too

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

where $c_n=\{\frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(b_n^2+2b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, $\infty>c\ge 2$. Assume that $|b_n|\le M_b$ and $|a_n|\le M_a$, thus
\begin{align}
|c_n| &= \left| \frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(b_n^2+2b_n) \right| \le \left| \frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(b_n+1)^2 \right| =\frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(b_n+1)^2 \le \frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(|b_n|+1)^2\\
&\le \frac{1}{c}(M_b+1)^2 < \infty, 
\end{align}
as such $c_n$ is a bounded sequence. Is it correct?

Edition after Nathaniel's B answer:

The last step changes into
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c^{a_n}}(b_n+1)^2 \le c^{|a_n|}(|b_n|+1)^2 \le c^{M_a}(M_b+1)^2 < \infty\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct, but your reasoning is slightly off.  When obtaining a bound for $b_n^2+2b_n$, you take the following route:
$$ |b_n^2+2b_n|\leq|b_n|^2+2|b_n|\leq |b_n|^2+2|b_n|+1=(|b_n|+1)^2.$$
As your proof currently stands, the first inequality is violated when $b_n=-0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Is $a_n$ necessarily greater than 1? If so, than your proof is correct (barring the observation of aweygan). If not, there is a problem.

For the final assertion to be true, it must also be that $1/c^{a_n}\leq 1/c$ which implies that $c\leq c^{a_n}$. Defining $a_n$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n$ contradicts this.

However, it can be proved that $1/c^{a_n}$ is bounded since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n>-\infty$ which can in turn be used to put a bound on $(1/c^{a_n})(M_b+1)^2$, giving the desired result.